# VsCode extension - get list of dark/light themes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to get list of installed light/dark themes in extension programmatically.

I want to make an extension that will switch next color theme on key command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all extensions and search for the ones that contribute a theme:

```typescript
vscode.extensions.all.forEach(ext => {
    console.log(ext.packageJSON.contributes.themes);
}
```

Comment: Where / how do you run the code?