# Can I get a list of all vscode themes installed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have tried

```
vscode.extensions.all.forEach(ext => {
  console.log(ext.packageJSON);
})
```

but it only returns non-theme extentions. Can;t find an api in the docs either.

Answer (score 1):

[The other related question on SO with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772368/vscode-extension-get-list-of-dark-light-themes?rq=1)

I've made another example:

```
    vscode.extensions.all.forEach(ext => {
        const contributesThemes = ext.packageJSON.contributes ? (ext.packageJSON.contributes.themes ? ext.packageJSON.contributes.themes : undefined) : undefined;
        if (contributesThemes) {
            for (var i = 0; i < contributesThemes.length; i++) {
                const label = contributesThemes[i].label;
                const uiTheme = (contributesThemes[i].uiTheme === 'vs-dark') ? 'dark' : 'light';
                const extensionType = ext.packageJSON.isBuiltin ? 'Built-in' : 'External';
                console.log(`${extensionType} extension '${ext.id}' contributes ${uiTheme} theme '${label}'`);
             }
        }
    });
```

This code prints all themes including built-in. The result is like:

```
...
Built-in extension 'vscode.theme-solarized-dark' contributes dark theme 'Solarized Dark'
Built-in extension 'vscode.theme-solarized-light' contributes light theme 'Solarized Light'
Built-in extension 'vscode.theme-tomorrow-night-blue' contributes dark theme 'Tomorrow Night Blue'
External extension 'eppz.eppz-code' contributes dark theme 'eppz!'
External extension 'jhaig343.asiimov-color-theme' contributes dark theme 'Asiimov'
External extension 'wesbos.theme-cobalt2' contributes dark theme 'Cobalt2'
```